# Ext js 6.2, Pin the west panel so that It won't collapse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I'm using Ext Js v6.2, In my application, **I have West panel, It can collapsed or expand**, But In that **I have Pin Tools Button**, **so if user click the Pin, Panel stay until user click unpin**, I'm newbie to Ext js, I've tried using panel expanded or collapsed but It doesn't help, please solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
tools: [{
    type: 'pin',
    cls: 'leftPanelPin',
    tooltip: 'Pin Panel',
    handler: function() {
        toggleCollapse: function() {
            if (this.lockedPanel) {
                this[this.collapsed ? 'expand' : 'collapse'](animate);
                return this;
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

​

Comment: Please provide a fiddle for better answer. link: http://www.jsonwrapper.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=tags&utm_campaign=queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `beforecollapse` listener to check whether the panel is pinned and return false, which will prevent the collapsing. Fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2aj8